# Newbie assistance with html code

Tags: html

I apologize if I dont do something correct hear but I was wondering if I could get some help on my errors and warnings with my html code. My code and functionality of my site is working as intended however I have quite a few errors listed.

I ran my code listed below through: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

it came back with 14 errors or warnings. I realize this is alot so any help will be appreciated here.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Chapter 4</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Lab4.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="http://www.randyconnolly.com/tests/process.php">
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Photo Details</legend>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
               <p>
               <label>Title</label><br/>
               <input type="text" name="title" size="80"/>
               </p>
               <p>
               <label>Description</label><br/>
               <textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="61">
               </textarea>
               </p>            
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> 
               <p> 
               <label>Continent</label><br/>
               <select name="continent">
                  <option>Choose continent</option> 
                  <option>Africa</option>
                  <option>Asia</option>
                  <option>Europe</option>
                  <option>North America</option>
                  <option>South America</option>
               </select>
               </p>
               <p> 
               <label>Country</label><br/>
               <select name="country">
                  <option>Choose country</option> 
                  <option>Canada</option>
                  <option>Mexico</option>
                  <option>United States</option>
               </select>
               </p>
               <p> 
               <label>City</label><br/>               
               <input type="text" name="city" list="cities"  size="40"/>
               <datalist id="cities">
                  <option>Calgary</option>                
                  <option>Montreal</option>
                  <option>Toronto</option>                  
                  <option>Vancouver</option>
               </datalist>
               </p>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="box">
                  <label>Copyright? </label><br/>
                  <input type="radio" name="copyright" value="1">All rights reserved<br/>
                  <input type="radio" name="copyright" value="2" checked>Creative Commons<br/>
               </div>
               <div class="box">
                  <label>Creative Commons Types </label><br/>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="cc" >Attribution <br/>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="cc" >Noncommercial <br/>    
                  <input type="checkbox" name="cc" >No Derivative Works <br/>  
                  <input type="checkbox" name="cc" >Share Alike
               </div>               
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2" >
            <div class="rectangle"> 
               <label>I accept the software license</label>
               <input type="checkbox" name="accept" >
            </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                  <p>
                  <label>Rate this photo: <br/>
                  <input type="number" min="1" max="5" name="rate" />  
                  </p>                  
                  <p>
                  <label>Color Collection: <br/>
                  <input type="color"  name="color" />   
                  </p>                  
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="box">
                  <p>
                  <label>Date Taken: <br/>
                  <input type="date"  name="date" />   
                  </p>
                  <p>
                  <label>Time Taken: <br/>
                  <input type="time"  name="time" />   
                  </p>                  
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
               <div class="rectangle centered"> 
                  <input type="submit" class="rounded"> <input type="reset" value="Clear Form" class="rounded">      
               </div
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have this one: `</div` this probably is not a good thing to have

Comment: The validator tells you what's wrong. What errors don't you understand?

Comment: I know your SO username doesn't show your name, but I believe your name is showing in the website. you may want to edit and add a fake website name.

Comment: The validator errors explanation is quite complete. Please edit the question with which errors you don't understand. Also bear in mind that some of the warnings given by the validator are not essential.

Answer (score 1):

Labels need a closing tag *(which none of yours have!)*. Change:

`<label>Rate this photo: <br/>` to `<label>Rate this photo: </label><br/>`

`<label>Color Collection: <br/>` to `<label>Color Collection: </label><br/>`

`<label>Date Taken: <br/>` to `<label>Date Taken: </label><br/>`

`label>Time Taken: <br/>` to `label>Time Taken: </label><br/>`

You've also missed a `>` on your closing `div` on line 111 - change `</div` to `</div>`

There are also some warnings regarding your `input` types. I would ignore these as long as your browser supports them. Other than that, you're good to go!

Comment: Thank you much. I will give that a try

Answer (score 0):

The Validator does give you the reasons why your code does not validate, but perhaps you don't quite understand (we all have to start somewhere), so here goes:

You've wrapped `<label>`, `<select>` and `<input>` elements in `<p>` tags. That's not good markup structure, so you ought to remove the `<p>` tags.

There are some `<label>` tags that need a closing `</label>` tag.

There is also a `</div>` tag without it's closing `>`.

The Time `<input>` type is probably not ready for general use yet:

http://caniuse.com/#search=time

Deal with those and you should be very close to validating. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I'm just starting out so I seen they gave the reason but didn't quite understand it. Thank you for your help